# Extracting values from duplicate rows and fitting them to a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe that has duplicate rows over a few columns(name,age,gender). I would like to identify all such rows and extract a unique column value(account_no) from each row. Those column values are to be fitted into a new dataframe(with columns source and target).

```
import pandas as pd

data={'name':['a','b','c','b','d','a','b','a','a'],'age':[28,22,22,22,25,28,22,22,22],'gender':['m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m'],'account_no':[101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109]}
dataset = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['name','age','gender','account_no'])
```

I am trying to achieve:

```
source    target    
101       106       
102       104
104       107
107       102
108       109
```

I have tried to find the duplicates and grouped them using groupby but could not figure out a way to fit them into new dataframe consisting columns source and target.

```
import pandas as pd

data={'name':['a','b','c','b','d','a','b','a','a'],'age':[28,22,22,22,25,28,22,22,22],'gender':['m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m','m'],'account_no':[101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109]}
dataset = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['name','age','gender','account_no'])
out = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Source','Target'])
df_res = pd.DataFrame()

duplicates = dataset[dataset.duplicated(subset=['name','age','gender'],keep=False)]
df_res = pd.concat(g for _, g in duplicates.groupby(['name','age','gender']) if len(g) > 1)
```

I am not able to find an approach that fits the account_no from the duplicate rows into a single row of out dataframe.
Please suggest an approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following approach:

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

d = df.groupby(['name','age','gender'])['account_no'] \
      .apply(lambda x: list(combinations(x, 2))) \
      .values

new = pd.DataFrame(sorted(chain.from_iterable(d)), columns=['source','target']) \
        .sort_values(['source','target'])
```

Result:

```
In [416]: new
Out[416]:
   source  target
0     101     106
1     102     104
2     102     107
3     104     107
4     108     109
```